# Could the ActiveMQ broker delete queues that has no active consumer for a long time automatically?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am developing a system that has multiple users just like this forum and I will create a queue for each user. However , if the user didn't login for a long time ,say , 3 months , I will delete that user's queue , in other words, I will delete any queue that has no active consumer for the last 3 months.  Could the activemq broker did this job automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. But you will delete queues that has been empty for some time, rather than queues without consumers.

Three monts seems like a very long time to clean up queues though and you likely want to clean up in the range of hours or minutes since queues actually allocates resources inside the broker.

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000">
   <destinationPolicy>
     <policyMap>
        <policyEntries>
           <policyEntry queue=">" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000"/>
        </policyEntries>
     </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>       
</broker>
```

[Reference](http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html)

Comment: The 3 months period is chosen intentively. [Here](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Is-it-possible-to-dispatch-a-message-in-the-topic-to-only-a-certain-queues-while-using-virtual-topic-td4672622.html) is the post which explains what I am trying to do. But the post is long enough to take minutes to read and I am sorry about that... However , if you could give me some tips about my system design I will really appreciate that.